# Doc2Vec find the similar sentence

Tags: python, nlp, gensim, doc2vec, sentence-similarity

I am trying find similar sentence using doc2vec. What I am not able to find is actual sentence that is matching from the trained sentences.

Below is the code from [this article](https://medium.com/@mishra.thedeepak/doc2vec-simple-implementation-example-df2afbbfbad5):

```
from gensim.models.doc2vec import Doc2Vec, TaggedDocument
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize
data = ["I love machine learning. Its awesome.",
        "I love coding in python",
        "I love building chatbots",
        "they chat amagingly well"]

tagged_data = [TaggedDocument(words=word_tokenize(_d.lower()), tags=[str(i)]) for i, _d in enumerate(data)]
max_epochs = 100
vec_size = 20
alpha = 0.025

model = Doc2Vec(size=vec_size,
                alpha=alpha, 
                min_alpha=0.00025,
                min_count=1,
                dm =1)
  
model.build_vocab(tagged_data)

for epoch in range(max_epochs):
    print('iteration {0}'.format(epoch))
    model.train(tagged_data,
                total_examples=model.corpus_count,
                epochs=model.iter)
    # decrease the learning rate
    model.alpha -= 0.0002
    # fix the learning rate, no decay
    model.min_alpha = model.alpha

model.save("d2v.model")
print("Model Saved")

model= Doc2Vec.load("d2v.model")
#to find the vector of a document which is not in training data
test_data = word_tokenize("I love building chatbots".lower())
v1 = model.infer_vector(test_data)
print("V1_infer", v1)

# to find most similar doc using tags
similar_doc = model.docvecs.most_similar('1')
print(similar_doc)


# to find vector of doc in training data using tags or in other words, printing the vector of document at index 1 in training data
print(model.docvecs['1'])
```

But the above code only gives me vectors or numbers. But how can I get the actual sentence matched from training data. For Eg - In this case I am expecting the result as "I love building chatbots".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The output of `similar_doc` is: `[('2', 0.991769552230835), ('0', 0.989276111125946), ('3', 0.9854298830032349)]`

This shows the similarity score of each document in the `data` with the requested document and it is sorted in descending order.

Based in this, `'2' index` in the `data` is the closest to the requested data i.e. `test_data`.

```
print(data[int(similar_doc[0][0])])
// prints: I love building chatbots
```

**Note:** this code is giving different results every time, maybe you need a better model or more training data.

Answer (score 2):

`Doc2Vec` isn't going to give good results on toy-sized datasets, so you shouldn't expect anything meaningful until using much more data.

But also, a `Doc2Vec` model doesn't retain within itself the full texts you supply during training. It just remembers the learned vectors for each text's `tag` – which is usually a unique identifier. So when you get back results from `most_similar()`, you'll be getting back `tag` values, which you then need to look-up yourself, in your own code/data, to retrieve full documents.

Separately:

Calling `train()` multiple times in a loop like you're doing is a bad and error-prone idea, as is managing `alpha`/`min_alpha` explicitly. You should not follow any tutorial/guide which recommends that approach.

Don't change the defaults for the `alpha` parameters, and call `train()` once, with your desired `epochs` count – and it will do the right number of passes, and right learning-rate management.

Answer (score 2):

To get the actual result you have to pass the text as a vector to most_simlar method to get the actual result. Hard coding the most_similar(1) will always give static results.

```
similar_doc = model.docvecs.most_similar([v1])
```

**Modified version of your code**

```
from gensim.models.doc2vec import Doc2Vec, TaggedDocument
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize
data = ["I love machine learning. Its awesome.",
        "I love coding in python",
        "I love building chatbots",
        "they chat amagingly well"]

def output_sentences(most_similar):
    for label, index in [('MOST', 0), ('SECOND-MOST', 1), ('MEDIAN', len(most_similar)//2), ('LEAST', len(most_similar) - 1)]:
      print(u'%s %s: %s\n' % (label, most_similar[index][1], data[int(most_similar[index][0])])))

tagged_data = [TaggedDocument(words=word_tokenize(_d.lower()), tags=[str(i)]) for i, _d in enumerate(data)]
max_epochs = 100
vec_size = 20
alpha = 0.025

model = Doc2Vec(size=vec_size,
                alpha=alpha, 
                min_alpha=0.00025,
                min_count=1,
                dm =1)

model.build_vocab(tagged_data)

for epoch in range(max_epochs):
    print('iteration {0}'.format(epoch))
    model.train(tagged_data,
                total_examples=model.corpus_count,
                epochs=model.iter)
    # decrease the learning rate
    model.alpha -= 0.0002
    # fix the learning rate, no decay
    model.min_alpha = model.alpha

model.save("d2v.model")
print("Model Saved")

model= Doc2Vec.load("d2v.model")
#to find the vector of a document which is not in training data
test_data = word_tokenize("I love building chatbots".lower())
v1 = model.infer_vector(test_data)
print("V1_infer", v1)

# to find most similar doc using tags
similar_doc = model.docvecs.most_similar([v1])
print(similar_doc)

# to print similar sentences
output_sentences(similar_doc) 


# to find vector of doc in training data using tags or in other words, printing the vector of document at index 1 in training data
print(model.docvecs['1'])
```

[Semantic “Similar Sentences” with your dataset-NLP](https://medium.com/es-magazine/semantic-similar-sentences-with-your-dataset-nlp-94fd1d49d231)

If you are looking for accurate prediction with your dataset and which is less, you can go for,

```
pip install similar-sentences
```